# Booting Android into web browser

Tags: android

Does anybody know how to boot Android into web browser directly? Kind of like autostart browser but the ultimate solution is to not have any desktop just browser. Thanks!

Comment: You'd need root access, for sure. If it's even possible. Ask on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) or [Android StackExchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/); this site is for developers and programming.

Comment: I am building my own system from sources so I do have root access. This is development related. But thanks for suggestions  to check in other places.

Comment: @Eric you are mistaken, root is not required.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Unless a custom firmware is installed (which the OP has, this wasn't specified), the home screen can be unset by any user of the device. If *not* using a custom firmware, root access would be required to do this otherwise.

Comment: @Eric, no, you are mistaken.  Root access is not required to install a custom home screen.  And installing a custom android build doesn't really prevent the user from uninstalling the home screen replacement, since if you can install a custom android build to limit them, they can probably just reinstall a normal android build that works properly instead.

Comment: @ChrisStratton A custom home screen can be unset by the user, as I said.

Comment: @Eric - sure, but a custom android version can be replaced by the user too.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Well, indeed, any device can be fully reset. There is no solution to any of this type of problem if that is taken as an antirequisite.

Comment: @Eric it's precisely because what you can do with root or a custom build can also be undone, that neither root nor a custom build is required.  There's little incremental benefit in going beyond the simple home screen replacement, which requires neither.  If the change proposed in the question is to the convenience of the user they will keep it; if it's to frustrate the user they will rightly revert it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I suppose that's true, however to enforce such a policy is possible if the user has control over the device itself. Having said that, I think we're... well, hijacking the OP, so this will be my last post. Excellent points made, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing you need your own browser. You need to change the AndroidManifest.xml and add below filter for Launcher Activity

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

And when home key is pressed, make Browser the default.

Comment: I do have own browser solution.  I will have a look on your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: If you are building from source, remove Launcher, the phone should launch right onto the browser But you may have trouble going to other apps

Answer (score 1):

Just create a home screen replacement which either is a browser, or launches one.  No further customization of android is needed.

The user can of course uninstall this, but that is generally a good thing.  With a custom android build you could seem to prevent that, but generally if the device will allow you to install a custom android build, it will also allow the user to install a different build to get around your restrictions.